# How to select an element with specific text from the HTML a element using JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I got an `a` element with few `attributes` one of them is `data-product-id` this is my element that I want.

for example `data-product-id="002212"` I am intrested in the number `"002212"`

My problem is that there can be couple `a` elements with this link

There is how link looks like.

```
<a href="something.com" title="test tile" class="title-product" data-jsevent="obj:title--product" data-product-name="test" data-product-id="002212" ddata-product-price="1.99" data-product-brand="test"  data-product-quantity="1">
```

I did something like this:

```
Elements links = document.select("a.title-product");
```

I receives every `a` element with class `title-product` now How can I get from received html `data-product-id` but with my number `002212`?

I can't parse `links` to String.

I also tried something like this:

```
if(links.contains("data-product-id=\"002212\"")){
                        System.out.println("it works");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("nothing");
                    }
```

But `links.contain`s equals always "`false`" even this number is there.

also I tried

it works but I get only first element with for example number 002211 instead of 002212

```
String linktext = a.attr("data-product-id");
```

and this is null

```
String linktext = a.attr("data-product-id=\"002212\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this line below did it.

```
Elements links = document.select("a[data-product-id=\"002212\"]");
```